# YouTube video don't load and play into android web-view

Tags: android, web, webview, youtube, android-webview

I am android developer & try to build a android application.This application load a web view(Which show a web-page).In this page there have some youtube video.When i load this page by web-view .It work perfectly.But when i try to play those video.then id don't able to show video and can't play the video .I can't understand what is error my code.Please check my code.

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Mobile screenshot :

[image]

If anyone know what is issue? Why it don't able to load video .please help to me.Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this library, you can copy their custom webView and custom webChrome client classes into your project and use instead standart views

https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest file and add internet permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

like this:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And in your main activity setPluginState property:

```
WebSettings w = webView.getSettings();      
w.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Comment: Hi @josedlujan ,I add those feature into java code and manifest file  .But don't work